# Passing value from Asp.Net to Extjs

Tags: asp.net, variables, extjs, extjs4

How to pass simple variable created in Asp.Net to Extjs? Lets say a variable in aspx.cs :

```
public string Name = "ASP.Net";
```

How to connect it with Extjs, let say a :

```
Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel",{

    width:100,
    width:100,
    title: <%=Name %>

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correct you have a .aspx page where you include a .js file that contains your javascript code?

You can't use server tags (`<%...%>`). There are, however, a few things you can do. The easiest is probably to define a javascript variable in your .aspx page and set the value from your server side variable. Then use that variable in your javascript. You can do that in this way:

*.aspx.cs code:

```
public string Name = "ASP.Net"
```

*.aspx code:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var title = "<%=Name%>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jsfile.js"></script>
```

*.js code:

```
Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel",{
    width:100,
    width:100,
    title: title
});
```

Make sure that you define the javascript variable before the .js file is included.

Comment: @Ingol, No problems, glad I could help. Also, please note that, opposed to what Muhammad Akhtar, you do need the quotation here as it is a string variable you are creating in javascript. Removing it will cause errors.